# MySQL 5.6 move rows into columns (pivot function)

Tags: mysql, pivot

We have the following input:

```
ID,MONTH,AMOUNT
1,1,1.1
1,2,2.1
1,3,3.1
```

We would like to output it as:

```
ID,AMOUNT_JAN,AMOUNT_FEB,AMOUNT_MAR
1,1.1,2.1,3.1
```

So far the query we got:

```
SELECT ID,
CASE WHEN MONTH = '1' THEN AMOUNT END AS AMOUNT_JAN,
CASE WHEN MONTH = '2' THEN AMOUNT END AS AMOUNT_FEB,
CASE WHEN MONTH = '3' THEN AMOUNT END AS AMOUNT_MAR
FROM TEST2
```

Can only generate outputs like the following:

```
ID,AMOUNT_JAN,AMOUNT_FEB,AMOUNT_MAR
1,1.1,NULL,NULL
1,NULL,2.1,NULL
1,NULL,NULL,3.1
```

Could any guru enlighten?

The SQL Fiddle is available here for your convenience:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/017d9c/3

Comment: The answers below should work just fine, but why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add `GROUP BY` and `MAX` function:

```
SELECT ID,
MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = '1' THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_JAN,
MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2' THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_FEB,
MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = '3' THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_MAR
FROM TEST2
GROUP BY ID
```

### SQLFiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `GROUP BY` and use *conditional aggregation* in the `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = '1' THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_JAN,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = '2' THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_FEB,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MONTH = '3' THEN AMOUNT END) AS AMOUNT_MAR
FROM TEST2
GROUP BY ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/017d9c/5)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could try along:

```
SELECT
  ID
  , (SELECT AMOUNT FROM TEST2 WHERE ID = T_outer.ID AND MONTH = 1) AS AMOUNT_JAN
  , (SELECT AMOUNT FROM TEST2 WHERE ID = T_outer.ID AND MONTH = 2) AS AMOUNT_FEB
  , (SELECT AMOUNT FROM TEST2 WHERE ID = T_outer.ID AND MONTH = 3) AS AMOUNT_MAR
FROM TEST2 T_outer
GROUP BY ID
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/017d9c/8).

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.